# Spring Social oAuth - Exception after redirection

Tags: java, spring, oauth, jackson, spring-social

I am using Spring Social and I get the following exception after redirection from facebook oauth page:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.index()I

my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Routes.ADD_OPINION)
public String addAction( ModelMap map, @RequestParam(value = "code",required = false) String token)
        throws IOException
{

    FacebookConnectionFactory f = new FacebookConnectionFactory(Config.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, Config.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

    String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080/eFirmApp" + Routes.SAVE_OPINION;

     if (token == null) {

            OAuth2Parameters p = new OAuth2Parameters();
            p.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
            p.setScope("public_profile");

            String r = f.getOAuthOperations().buildAuthorizeUrl(p);

            return ("redirect:" + r);

            // return this.facebookService.redirectToAuth();
        }

    AccessGrant accessGrant = f.getOAuthOperations()
            .exchangeForAccess(token, redirectUri, null);

    Connection<Facebook> connection = f.createConnection(accessGrant);

   return this.getControllerActionView("show", "company");
}
```

Log :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.index()I
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:465)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.constructCreatorProperty(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:436)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:325)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:266)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:266)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:399)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:348)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:261)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:241)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:191)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:345)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:2072)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:160)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:657)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:521)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:259)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:202)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:53)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:49)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:42)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:30)
at org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.setValues(AbstractConnection.java:174)
at org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.initKey(AbstractConnection.java:137)
at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection.<init>(OAuth2Connection.java:75)
at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:91)
at core.common.service.FacebookService.createGrantedConnection(FacebookService.java:49)
at core.modules.main.controller.OpinionController.saveOpinionAction(OpinionController.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, you have jar version conflicts.

Check Jackson library you are using, and the one required by Spring Social.

You can know requirements, by checking related pom.xml (For example through mvnrepository.com
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook/1.1.1.RELEASE)

Latest version of Spring Social Facebook - 1.1.1.RELEASE, for example depends on

> JSON Lib  com.fasterxml.jackson.core  jackson-annotations 2.3.2
>
> JSON Lib  com.fasterxml.jackson.core  jackson-core    2.3.2
>
> JSON Lib  com.fasterxml.jackson.core  jackson-databind    2.3.2

Comment: That's it! I have already tried with different version of JSON lib but still wrong. Now i have latest social-facebook and jackson dependencies like above, i also changed java-servlet-api to 3.0.1. and it works. Thank you for your response